# Python. Поддержка аудио в Pyqt5 разными ОС

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qt5, аудио

Не так давно начал изучать python и вместе с ним PyQt5.

Сделал , грубо говоря , "проигрыватель" с помощью QtMultimedia , QMediaPlayer.

И вот теперь задаюсь вопросами: на всех ли ОС с поддержкой EXE будет работать, если не на всех , то на каких не будет и как это можно будет исправить?

Компилировал в EXE через PyInstaller

Comment: а ты знаешь много ОС с поддержкой .exe?)

Comment: Мне кажется, или заголовок не соответствует содержимому вопроса?

Comment: PyInstaller замораживает (упаковывает) приложения Python в автономные исполняемые файлы под Windows, GNU / Linux, Mac OS X, FreeBSD, Solaris и AIX.